# Irreducible representations of $S_5$ and their Young diagrams

Tags: group-theory, permutations, representation-theory, young-tableaux

Given a Young tableau, we can construct its Young symmetrizer $c_\lambda$. Then, the ideal $\mathbb{C} S_n \cdot c_\lambda$ is an irreducible representation of $S_n$. Exercise 4.5 in Fulton and Harris asks the reader to find which Young diagrams correspond to which irreps for $S_3, S_4$, and $S_5$. It's easy for $S_3$: the diagram $(1, ..., 1)$ always corresponds to the sign representation, the diagram $(n)$ always corresponds to the trivial representation, so the diagram $(2, 1)$ must correspond to the remaining representation.

How do I connect diagrams to irreps for $S_4$ and $S_5$? I don't know what I'm really supposed to use here beside the characters of the irreps. The representations of $S_4$ and $S_5$ have previously been constructed geometrically.

EDIT: It seems that I failed to communicate my question well, so I'll try to clarify. For $S_5$, I know that there are 7 irreps corresponding to different Young diagrams by means of the Young symmetrizer. The question is, how do I learn any of their properties, such as dimensions or characters? Since one can identify the irreps of $S_5$ by other means, one way would to connect the known irreps to the Young diagrams. For example, if we make a 5-dimensional representation of $S_5$ by permuting the basis vectors of $\mathbb{C}^5$, this representation is a sum of two irreps: trivial and a four-dimensional representation $V$. This representation corresponds to some Young diagram, but I don't see a way to find which one.

Comment: It’s unclear what you’re asking: given a partition of 4, for example $(2,1,1)$, you can write down a Young symmetriser and therefore get an irrep of $S_4$: what more do you want? You might ask for a nice description of a basis of that irrep?

Comment: @Joppy Let me explain. I know that $S_4$ has five irreps, and I know their nice descriptions: trivial, sign, a two-dimensional one, and two three-dimensional ones: rotations of a cube and rotations+reflections of a tetrahedron. I would like to know which of them corresponds to which partition of 4.

Comment: There are well-known theorems about the irreducible corresponding to the partition $\lambda$: for example the dimension is the number of standard Young tableaux with shape $\lambda$, and there is a way to calculate the character at any conjugacy class $\mu$. There is too much to say here - you are probably better off finding a book or set of notes which goes through the representation of the symmetric group in more detail.

Comment: @Joppy I see, thank you!

Comment: This is a well known book containing all the needed information https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Representation_Theory_of_the_Symmetr.html?id=0WcPAQAAMAAJ